# Update BackupBuddy with WP-CLI

Tags: wp-cli

I've written a script that basically loops through all of the WP sites on our server and updates everything: core, plugins, themes.

It does, however run into one issue: It will not update BackupBuddy. It will update 4 other premium plugins from various companies. I receive the following when trying to update it:

```
$wp plugin update backupbuddy
Warning: Download failed. Forbidden
Success: Translations updates are not needed for the 'English (US)' locale.
Error: Updated 0/1 plugins.
Enabling Maintenance mode...
Downloading update from https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.ithemes.com/products/plugins/backupbuddy/backupbuddy-6.3.3.3.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=******&Expires=******&Signature=******...
Disabling Maintenance mode...
```

I also receive an issue if I try to update the plugin through Jetpack Manage: `An error occurred while updating BackupBuddy on WEBSITE NAME.`

I have found that if I physically login to the WP Admin, and then run the command in WP-CLI, I can update without an issue. Also, the same happens when I first login to the site, and then try to update it through Jetpack Manage.

The leads me to believe that BackupBuddy requires one to be logged in to update the plugin, which is difficult when managing multiple sites.

iThemes support has told me:

> You could use something like iThemes Sync or a similar service. Since
>   BackupBuddy uses licensing it may not be compatible with 3rd party
>   updaters like wp-cli.

I'll pay if I have to, but it's hard to justify purchasing software to just update one single plugin, especially when that plugin includes it's own wp-cli commands to make backups.

Is there a way to either spoof a login from WP-CLI or do something else that can update it from the command line, or is iThemes Sync my only option?

**Versions:**

- WP-CLI: 0.20.1
- WordPress: 4.3.1
- BackupBuddy: Varies, but no older
  than 5.2.0.0. Newest version that's not updated is 6.2.2.4.

**Edit:**

Other things I've tried have been to pass the `--user=MYEMAIL@DOMAIN.COM` flag, but I get the same error. It's a global parameter for WP-CLI, but I'm not quite sure what it does I guess.

I know that I can use the `--require` flag to require a PHP file, but I have no clue if there's a file I can add to authenticate a user, and I worry about security if I created a file to auto-login. Then again, maybe there's a BackupBuddy file that can be required to authorize it.

Another option is the `--url` flag. I tried using `--url=http://DOMAIN.COM/wp-admin` but that didn't work either. I still got the `Download failed. Forbidden` notice.

The only time I've had success when updating is if a coworker has logged into the site with their username, so it feels likes there's almost an expires nonce or transient that is set when someone logs in, allowing the download to be performed.

Comment: If iThemes (the official supplier of BackupBuddy, correct?) says that the way to do it is to purchase iThemes Sync, then that's your answer. This site is not meant for *"How can I get around Company X's business model?"*-type questions.

Comment: @PatJ I updated the question to include their response. They don't say iThemes Sync is the only way. My goal in asking is to reduce the amount of work needed to update sites, hence I'm not looking for a "similar service", but a way to be able to update everything with a script. _This isn't meant to get around their business model_, as they don't say it's the only way, especially considering that updating BackupBuddy with WP-CLI works when logged in to the Admin, but is meant to _save time_. It doesn't make sense that a site that has its own WP-CLI extension can't easily be updated with WP-CLI.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've been Googling WP-CLI, trying to see if there's a way to pass in a cookie, but so far haven't found anything.

Comment: Yeah, I've been searching all over. Probably long enough that I could manually update the plugins myself. :P But once I have this figured out, I won't have to ever again. It's looking like I have two options. **1.** Purchase iThemes Sync and periodically go through and update BackupBuddy from their site. **2.** Change my script to check if BackupBuddy needs to be updated, and if so delete the current plugin and install it from another zip on the server (manually adding it, so it doesn't solve my making life easier problem), but that could get messy. I'm thinking iThemes Sync may be best.

Comment: You are missing authentication. Please [edit] your question with what you have tried after you have tried and failed something into that direction.

Comment: @kaiser I've edited the question to include other things I've tried, but I'm not sure how much help that will be. I think I've just accepted it's not possible to update BackupBuddy with WP-CLI.

Comment: Hm. You ask Daniel Hüsken `@danielhuesken` and Frank Bueltge `@bueltge` on Twitter and ask if you can pull in [BackWPUp](https://marketpress.de/product/backwpup-pro/?noredirect=de_DE) instead. Else I'd try to get in contact with iThemes and ask them about the permission issue. Also please rephrase your question and call it around "WP CLI Update from private repo". It's not specific to that plugin, right?

Comment: @kaiser I shouldn't rephrase the question because this is specific to BackupBuddy. Other premium plugins on a private repos work, and I have plugins I've written on private repos that I also can update with WP-CLI.